# Getting financial history using R

Tags: r

I want to take  minute-long history of the usd/btc exchange rate interactively, I found this site http://www.coindesk.com/price/

Note: ( if you think there is a more convenient site for this task, I'll be glad if you share it. I don't want every time download csv. Moreover it is incorrect.)
But I don't know how to use `R` to collect information.

Is it possible using R to connect and collect minute  data on the exchange rate of USD / BTC?

Ideal output.
`1h` button for minutes exchange rate

```
dmy mm             exchange
12.09.2018 13:45    6200
12.09.2018 13:46    6300
12.09.2018 13:46    6400
```

Collection must be continuous, my server is very rarely turned off.

[image: exchange]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get raw data from coindesk using their API: https://www.coindesk.com/api/

For example, you can get the current price of bitcoin in USD by visiting this URL: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json. I suggest you set up a script to retrieve this data once every minute.

Or you can get a recent history of the price at this endpoint: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json, though note this only the *daily* price.

To learn how to retrieve data from an API using R I suggest you follow a tutorial such as this one: https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-access-any-restful-api-using-r-language/how-to/2017/07/21.

Comment: this link https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json  How can i set to every minutes?  it contain {"time":{"updated":"Sep 14, 2018 09:22:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2018-09-14T09:22:00+00:00","updateduk":"Sep 14, 2018 at 10:22 BST"},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org","bpi":{"USD":{"code":"USD","rate":"6,457.2475","description":"United States Dollar","rate_float":6457.2475}}}.  Can you hint me.

Comment: That page will only display the price at the latest minute, so what you want to do is schedule a script to visit that URL once every minute and save the result each time.

Comment: i see.  But Can't  understand how to set the schedule. Is there topic in SO, how set schedule or can you help me do it. If it is need i can create new post.

Comment: It depends what type of operating system you are on. If windows, then you want to use the windows task scheduler https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/scheduling-r-tasks-via-windows-task-scheduler/. If mac or linux then you can use cron https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/schedule-rscript-with-cron/.